# I have a series of sequences and am looking for a general algorithm to find out if they have convergent subsequences.

Tags: analysis

I have a series of sequences similar to the ones below and I am wondering if there is a general method to use to find out if a sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Which of the following sequences have convergent subsequences?

> (a) $(\sin(n + 2014))_{n=1}^{\infty}$
>
> (b) $\Big(\frac{n \cos^n(n)}{ \sqrt{n^2 +n}}\Big)_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Answer (score 0):

Both of your sequences have convergent subsequences because they are infinite and take values in a compact set $[-1,1]$ (This is a theorem about compactness in ${\mathbb R}^d$). I believe that in fact both of your sequences are dense in that range. The first one certainly is, and the second is harder to see but I believe it still is dense. If you like, I can update with proof of denseness but that isn't what you asked.

Comment: Are you able to explain to me if the sequence in (b) is convergent and if so what it coverages to?